# How can I access & store data in the sdcard  across all Android devices?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

The Samsung GalaxyS  has a folder named external_sd inside sdcard. I want to access this. I don't want to hard code the path `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "external_sd/"`.

I want the general path for all devices to store by default in sdcard. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the externalstorage directory using this:

[getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String Type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)

You can specify the file type and you get the location where you can store the file. This is the same space also used by the mobile user.

An alternative is to use the storage space for your own application. For that use,

[getExternalFilesDir(String Type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

This space is application specific and will be deleted when the app is uninstalled. The user will not be able to see this files.